# How to change Android DatePicker Dialog's "Dividers" Colors

Tags: android, datepicker, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to create a custom dialog, basically I'm using `DatePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK` but I want to change the "divider" color and the text color.

[image]

I want to change the blue lines and the text color to red.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Using this code:

```
<style name="testo" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/dialog_divider</item>
</style>
```

This is what I get:
[image]

The drawable for the divider is basically a red line..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own theme that extends THEME_HOLO_DARK. [Change basic theme color of android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688724/change-basic-theme-color-of-android-application)

Edit: Try something like this

```
<style name="testo" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/MyDivider</item>
</style>
```

And pass the reference to your theme to the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)

Comment: I can't extend THEME_HOLO_DARK is it the same as Theme.black? And if I try to set android:_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1 i get this error: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
 'android:_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1'.

Comment: You should be able to extend THEME_HOLO_DARK. Did you define _DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1 in your resources?

Comment: This is what i have now: <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />

    <style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" > 
       <item name="android:_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1">#FFFFFF</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style> 
</resources>how can i define that in my resources?

Comment: I've edited my question. I believe you've found the right theme to extend, now I have to figure out which attributes to set, and how to set them properly. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @KarimVarela The question is tagged Android 4.0 which is API 14.

Comment: @Robin.v In-detail analysis here: [Android: how to change the color of the datepicker divider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider).

Answer (score 1):

add this item to your main theme

```
<item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/MyApp.NumberPicker</item>
```

set custom divider color in this style

```
<style name="MyApp.NumberPicker" parent="Widget.Holo.NumberPicker">
   <item name="selectionDivider">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

EDIT : tested only on HoloEverywhere

Comment: "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'numberPickerStyle'."

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late reply but I would like to share my findings with those who experienced or will experience this problem in the future.

I searched many places, and the only solution I found was SimonVT's Pickers.

After implementing the library, it was very easy to change the colors. In numberpicker- the library uses images that can be simply replaced with the desired designs.

This example has three pickers: NumberPicker, DatePicker and TimerPicker.

https://github.com/rodrigobusata/android-pickers

I hope you find it useful.

**UPDATED**

The above link do not existe anymore, now you must use Material Design https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

Here, dialog is an object of DatePickerDialog.

```
    int dividerId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier
            ("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    View divider = dialog.findViewById(dividerId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

    int textViewId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier
            ("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(textViewId);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     fun applyStyLing(timePickerDialog: DatePickerDialog,context: Context) {

        try {
            var dividerId = timePickerDialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android")
            val divider = timePickerDialog.findViewById<View>(dividerId)
            divider.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorDatePicker))

            var dividerId1 = timePickerDialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android")
            val divider1 = timePickerDialog.findViewById<TextView>(dividerId1)
            divider1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorDatePicker))

            val system = Resources.getSystem()
            val hourNumberPickerId = system.getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")
            val minuteNumberPickerId = system.getIdentifier("month", "id", "android")
            val ampmNumberPickerId = system.getIdentifier("year", "id", "android")

            val hourNumberPicker = timePickerDialog.findViewById<View>(hourNumberPickerId) as NumberPicker
            val minuteNumberPicker = timePickerDialog.findViewById<View>(minuteNumberPickerId) as NumberPicker
            val ampmNumberPicker = timePickerDialog.findViewById<View>(ampmNumberPickerId) as NumberPicker

            setNumberPickerDividerColour(hourNumberPicker,context)
            setNumberPickerDividerColour(minuteNumberPicker,context)
            setNumberPickerDividerColour(ampmNumberPicker,context)

        }catch (e:Exception)
        {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }


private fun setNumberPickerDividerColour(number_picker: NumberPicker,context: Context) {
        val count = number_picker.childCount

        for (i in 0 until count) {

            try {
                val dividerField = number_picker.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider")
                dividerField.isAccessible = true
                val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDatePicker))
                dividerField.set(number_picker, colorDrawable)

                number_picker.invalidate()
            } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTxtClr", e)
            } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTxtClr", e)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.w("setNumberPickerTxtClr", e)
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can change the text color by doing something like

`<style name="testo" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">`

`<item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>`

`</style>`

Did you ever figure out how to change the divider color?  I'm trying to do the same thing and can't really find anything at the moment.

Comment: In-detail analysis here: [Android: how to change the color of the datepicker divider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider).

Comment: -1 Not only does this code not work, but it fails to answer the second half of the question (`divider` colors). Please keep your questions in comments, not answers.