# Date Picker is messed up

Tags: android, calendar, datepicker

so im creating a program that displays a `DatePicker`, but every time i run it on my device, im getting this output here is the picture :

[image]

and i want to change that into this :

[image]

how can i do that? Thanks :)

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254093/date-and-time-picker-dialog?rq=1
And read this http://www.filefactory.com/file/6mf3bl0alkhf/n/DateTimePicker_zip I am not sure but may help you. If doesn't then comment

Answer (score 0):

set the "android:calendarViewShown" value to false like below and you are done

```
        <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
         />
```