# Date and time picker in same dialogbox

Tags: android, xml, datepicker, datetimepicker

How can I show Date picker and time picker in the same dialog box ?
If I' using

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

what should be done on **MainAcitiviy.java**
I'm new to android. I  searched but didnt get anything,,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254093/date-and-time-picker-dialog Try this link

Comment: Try [DateTimePicker](https://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put both Date Picker and Time Picker in a layout XML: [Referring this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055509/datetime-picker-in-android-application)
**date_time_picker.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<DatePicker
android:id="@+id/date_picker"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:calendarViewShown="true"
android:spinnersShown="false"
android:layout_weight="4"
android:layout_height="0dp" />

<TimePicker
android:id="@+id/time_picker"
android:layout_weight="4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:text="Set"
android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The code**

```
    final View dialogView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.date_time_picker, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();

dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
         TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
    datePicker.getMonth(),
    datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
     timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

         time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
         alertDialog.dismiss();
    }});
    alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get both date and time from single dialog.

Use following Code:

```java
new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(getActivity())
 // .bottomSheet() 
 // .curved() .title("Select Date")
 .titleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
 .minutesStep(1)
 .backgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.smokewhite))
 .mainColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
 .listener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener()
 {
   @Override public void onDateSelected(Date date)
    {
       // selectpackages();
       String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
       // String DATE_FORMAT_NOW1 = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
       //  SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW1);

       stringDate = sdf.format(date);

       getDateDifference(stringDate);

       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+stringDate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }).display();
```

Use this dependency:
compile `'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial to start : <s>http://www.androidapplicationdevelopment.guru/2014/06/custom-dialog-box-in-android-with-example.html</s>

Just follow what he's doing, but put your layout with the TimePicker and DatePicker instead of his dialog.xml (rewrite it so that it doesn't display a kitty cat but your pickers)

Hope this helps!