# change datepicker, time picker and dialog separators color

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, datetimepicker

Here is my date and time picker:
[image]

I want to change the separator color from blue to red.
Can i do that?

Comment: are you talking about divider?

Comment: yes, the bluue devider between Jan and Dec

Comment: You should go for styles..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688724/change-basic-theme-color-of-android-application have a look at this .. using this you can change your app theme fully

Answer (score -1):

```
 <style name="myStylr" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
   <item name="android:divider">@drawable/MyDivider</item>
 </style>
```

Set this style to your Time,Date Picker

Comment: @android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker requires API level 14 (current min is 
 8)

Comment: @haythemsouissi In-detail analysis here: [Android: how to change the color of the datepicker divider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider).