# Change Divider Color Android DatePicker Dialog

Tags: android, colors, datepicker, divider

I´m tying to change the divider color of the DatePicker Dialog.

I create the style:

```
<style name="dialog_custom" parent="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/dialog_divider</item>
    </style>
```

And create the drawable like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30331820/dialog_divider.png)

And the result is [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30331820/device-2013-02-13-090847.png)

The divider no change color and the dialog take the content size..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using theme. Check accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688724/change-basic-theme-color-of-android-application). i think it will helpful to you.

**UPDATES**

Expand `res` folder in your application and expand `values` folder. Then create `themes.xml` file on `values` folder. then replace all code in `themes.xml` file with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MYTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">

       <item name="android:divider">@drawable/dialog_divider</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Then open your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. and find  `android:theme` and replcae with `android:theme="@style/MYTheme"`

Comment: When I do this I get this error: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1'.

Comment: Did you define `_DEFAULT_BASE_COLOR_1` in your resources ?

Comment: Sorry but...What resources? How I can define it?

Comment: I try generate all resources with this, http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html. But the default color of the dividers no change..

Comment: sorry but i get this error again..see the link https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30331820/ERROR.png

Comment: updated my answer with `<item name="android:divider">@drawable/dialog_divider</item>`

Comment: I set a style with android-ui-utils.googlecode.com like this:    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider_dialog</item>
        <item name="android:editTextB....
    </style>, with all the nine-patch drawables but this line blue not change. I create de "dialog_divider" like a nine-patch and put in the style but the line blue persist...any way to change the blue line divider in android style holo.light?

Comment: Did you find any solution? This answer is accepted but doesn't provide any…

Comment: @Kernald In-detail analysis  here: [Android: how to change the color of the datepicker divider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider).

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to change divider colors in NumberPickers, TimePickers, DatePickers and the TimePickerDialog. For DatePickerDialog you can call DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker()

```
public class NumberPickerStylingUtils {

private static final Drawable PICKER_DIVIDER_DRAWABLE = //Place your drawable here

private NumberPickerStylingUtils() {}

public static void applyStyling(TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog) {
    try {
        Field field = TimePickerDialog.class.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        applyStyling((TimePicker) field.get(timePickerDialog));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void applyStyling(TimePicker timePicker) {
    try {
        Field fields[] = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getType().equals(NumberPicker.class)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                applyStyling((NumberPicker) field.get(timePicker));
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void applyStyling(DatePicker datePicker) {
    try {
        Field fields[] = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getType().equals(NumberPicker.class)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                applyStyling((NumberPicker) field.get(datePicker));
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void applyStyling(NumberPicker numberPicker) {
    try {
        Field field = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(numberPicker, PICKER_DIVIDER_DRAWABLE));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}